# Авторизация PHP. Проверка пароля

Tags: php

Кто может пояснить код, приведенный из статьи на хабре:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/175133/

Вот этот участок кода:

```
// проверяем пароль
if (PassHash::check_password($user['pass_hash'], $_POST['password']) {
    // доступ разрешён
    // ...
} else {
    // доступ запрещён
    // ...
}
```

Ясно, что `$_POST['password']` данные из формы, тогда `$user['pass_hash']` для чего? 
Где должен быть запрос в БД?

Comment: ну туториал плохой, и в комментах там об этом написано. доступ к базе, видимо до того, когда $user создается, зачем создавать $user до авторизации мне не ясно, почему просто не сделать 

   SELECT user.* from user WHERE login=? and hash=?

...

Comment: Более того, при проверке пароля - там генерируется новая соль, которая применяется к введенному паролю. Тогда вообще авторизация невозможна.

Comment: Думаю лучшим вариантом будет применение:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/194972/

Comment: нет, там новая соль не генерируется

Comment: `$user['pass_hash']` необходим для того, чтобы достать из него соль. В данном примере, очевидно, соль не хранится отдельно, а дописывается в начало пароля.

Comment: Для всех версий PHP? Что тогда можете посоветовать?

Comment: Буду рад хорошему примеру по данному вопросу

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, это та тема, в которой хорошо не просто знать единственный алгоритм, как сделать, а максимально детально разобраться, вплоть до алгоритмов хеширования (я туда пока так и не добрался). Могу посоветовать в первую очередь любимого Этвуда http://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/ http://blog.codinghorror.com/speed-hashing/